# Is there an $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-curve of geometric genus 3 and $\mathbb{F}_{\!q^3}$-cover to an elliptic $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-curve of $j$-invariant 0?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, jacobians

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3 + b$ (of $j$-invariant $0$) over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$ such that $3 \mid (q-1)$. Is there an absolutely irreducible $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-curve $C$ of geometric genus $3$ and non-constant $\mathbb{F}_{\!q}$-conjugate covers (of a small degree) $\varphi = \varphi^{(3)}\!: C \to E$, $\varphi^{(1)}\!: C \to E$, and $\varphi^{(2)}\!: C \to E$? How to explicitly construct such covers if any? Here, $\varphi^{(i)}$ is obtained by raising the coefficients of $\varphi$ to the power $q^i$. It is worth noting that always $E(\mathbb{F}_{\!q^3})[2] \simeq (\mathbb{Z}/2)^2$, which possibly simplifies finding the desired $\mathbb{F}_{\!q^3}$-map $\varphi$. According to a recent [article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00145-023-09474-2), there is progress on the given topic. Hence, my question does not seem intractable.